# .htaccess mod_rewrite domains to subdirectories (multiple sites)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am attempting to rewrite domains to subdirectories in my hosting provider using .htaccess files since I do not have access to the Apache config files. In my web directory I have a Wordpress installation in the web root directory (/home/www/). Say the domain www.main-site.com points to this site. This WP install serves my main website.

Then within this directory I have 3 other Wordpress installations which I host for customers. The file structure looks like (/home/www/example1, /home/www/example2, and /home/www/example3). Each of these websites will need it's own domain. (ie. www.example1.com, www.example2.com, www.example3.com).

How can I use .htaccess files to ensure that when someone hits www.main-site.com, they land at my personal website, but when they navigate to www.example1.com, it points them to the subdirectory '/example1'?

Currently, if I go to www.main-site.com everything works fine. Also, if I go to www.example1.com, it correctly forwards to my subdirectory site (I think that's set up automatically through my web hosting provider's admin panel.) But, once I click the first link to go to a different page on www.example1.com, instead of it looking like www.example1.com/new-page.html, it looks like www.main-site.com/example1/new-page.html. You can see it's pulling in my main site's url. I don't want this.

Any thoughts?

My code is below.

**Code in my web root .htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Code in my subdirectory's .htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example1/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Ok, an update. It appears that the way I was generating the menu in Wordpress was producing unfavorable links that were hardcoded to 'www.main-site.com/example1/the_link_here...'. So, I fixed that and now when I hover on links on the site, they correctly say 'www.example1.com/about' for example. When I click on the links, they look correct in the address bar now, but all I get is an error document.

Comment: Another update... Just tried updating the .htaccess file in my subdirectory. Commented out the line that reads `RewriteRule . /example1/index.php [L]` and added these two lines: `RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example1.com$` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /example1/$1/ [L]`. I'm getting a 403 now.